# Почему js код так не понятно работает

Tags: javascript

Есть 2 кода с виду не чем не отличаются но функционал режется, почему?

```
document.querySelector('.footer_btn').addEventListener('click', function(){
    document.querySelectorAll('.invisible').forEach(function(elem){
        elem.classList.toggle('invisible')
        console.log(elem)
    })
});
```

В этом коде `elem.classList.toggle('invisible')` только удаляется при повторном клике не добавляется.

```
let hidden = document.querySelectorAll('.invisible');
document.querySelector('.footer_btn').addEventListener('click', function(){
    hidden.forEach(function(elem){
        elem.classList.toggle('invisible')
        console.log(elem)
    })
});
```

но когда мы задали глобальную переменную с классом invisible всё работает корректно, почему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что в первом варианте кода Вы каждый раз делаете выборку элементов по `.invisible`, но после первого цикла с `toggle` таких элементов на странице нет.